# Why is ng-required forcing ng-model value to be established?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following markup:

```
<input id="bestCost" name="bestCost" ng-model="vm.active.bestCost" ng-required="vm.active.funded == true" />
```

I have a method in my controller that sets `vm.active = null`. This value remains null, until at some time I fire off an asynchronous request. After the request is fired, Angular triggers a digest. As a result, by the time the success handler of the asynchronous promise executes, `vm.active` is no longer null. It is an object with bestCost as null:

```
Object {bestCost: null}
```

None of my other template bindings do this, just this field. The only difference between the other form fields and this one is this one has an `ng-required` directive.

**Is there a way to prevent this from happening?** I understand Angular will gracefully create an object hierarchy for form fields / bindings as the user enters them, but I really don't want the `ng-required` directive to do this.

Comment: `vm` is generally what you use inside of the controller. Is your `controllerAs` defined to be `vm` as well?

Comment: Yes, inside controller I have `var vm = this;` I also have `controllerAs` set to `vm`

Comment: @Makoto Angular at one point used to have `controllerAs vm` on their documentation pages so that `vm` would be used in the view as OP does...

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand what you're asking.

You could use the fact that `&&` will not evaluate all terms if earlier ones are false and that in JavaScript (which AngularJS expressions are based off) truth-y and false-y are used instead of strict boolean values.

```
ng-required="vm && vm.active && vm.active.funded == true"
```

Also you could leverage `ng-if` to make the `input` element not show up in the DOM (and the `ng-required` expression wouldn't even be evaluated) by wrapping the element in a tag with an `ng-if` - if it's having to make a async request before the element is usable this may not be a bad thing (if the user interacts with the `input` element before the async request finishes then the `ng-model` will create the `vm.active`):

```
<div ng-if="vm.active">
  <input id="bestCost" name="bestCost" ng-model="vm.active.bestCost" ng-required="vm.active.funded == true" />
</div>
```

Comment: I really hoped this would work, but unfortunately it did not. Though I really question why it does not, because you are completely correct with how JS will short circuit the following predicate clauses

Comment: @spoof3r Can you make a Plunker demonstrating the problem?  Also see my second option about the `ng-if`.

Comment: I could also suggest that you set in your controller `vm.active.funded` to a default value such as `null` or `false`, same for `bestCost`
Your `ng-required` would still work as expected
But you would need your if to change to `ng-if=vm.active.funded != null` for example

Answer (score 0):

I had what I think was the same problem with this situation:

```
<form name="activeItemForm">
   <input type="text" ng-model="activeItem.itemRef" ng-required="activeItem.type === 'product'">
   <!-- ...other controls -->
</form>
```

When trying to nullify **activeItem** like this (from the controller):

```
$scope.activeItem = null;
```

...I was left with activeItem being an object:

```
{ itemRef: null }
```

Adding **ng-if** to the whole form solves it:

```
<form name="activeItemForm" ng-if="activeItem">
```